# using int selector for ccmenuitem

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, menuitem

My CCMenuItem has two methods in selector

```
        menuItem = [[CCMenuItemSprite
                         itemFromNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"menuItem.png"]
                         selectedSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"menuItem.png"]
                         target:self
                         selector:@selector(methodName:anotherParam:)] retain];
```

I'd like to send the an int from CCMenuItem so that I'd could switch the cases based on the int of the CCMenuItem

something like this:

```
- (void)methodName:(id *)sender anotherParam:(int *)intNumber {
    CCMenuItemSprite *menuItem = (CCMenuItemSprite *)sender;

    switch (anotherParam) {
        case 1:
        //My case
        break;
}
```

How can I send an int from CCMenuItem in order to switch my cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tag the CCMenuItem:

```
menuItem.tag = 1;
```

Then get it from the sender parameter:

```
- (void)methodName:(id *)sender { 

    switch ([sender tag]) {
       //cases depending on tag
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want that much cases... only few of them

Comment: I've grouped my CCMenuitems into cases and want to remove in a certain order; disabled all except frist case and I'm getting them by tag to enable it

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand what you mean sorry. If you have given them all a tag, I don't see what the issue is.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `userData` property of a `CCNode` for this, or you could set an associated object.

Eample:

```
CCNode *myNode = [CCNode node];
myNode.userData = (void *) intVal;

// in callback
CCNode *myNode = (CCNode *) sender;
int anotherParam = (int) myNode.userData;
```

To set an associated object, you would do something like this:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(myObject, "anotherParam", (id) myInt, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);

// in callback
int anotherParam = (int) objc_getAssociatedObject(myObject, "anotherParam");
```

Note that key is of type `void *` so you could put any value there (`NSObject`, `NSString`, `C-string`, `int` value, etc.)

Comment: Where I should place `objc_setAssociatedObject` ?

Comment: @el.severo when you initialize the object.

Comment: Complier complains with the following errors: `Implicit declaration of function 'obj_setAssociatedObject' is invalid in C99` & `Use of undeclared identifier 'OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN'`

Comment: Did you import `<objc/runtime.h>`? And the function is `objc_setAssociatedObject`, not `obj_setAssociatedObject`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7387/discussion-between-el-severo-and-richard-j-ross-iii)